# how to catch the event of changing current visible period of jquery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I use jquery fullcalendar, I want to get informed when the time period visible now is changed, i.e. arrows in the top left are pressed, or view changed to week. I want to do this to load only the events of interest from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the viewRender event handler. It is triggered when someone changes the date range, or when they change between day, week, month, year, etc... view.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewRender/